# An Infinite non-nilpotent group whose every maximal subgroup is a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

It is widely known that for every finite group $G$, $G$ is nilpotent If and only if every maximal subgroup of $G$ is a normal subgroup.

But I don't know **if there is an infinite non-nilpotent group whose every maximal subgroup is a normal subgroup**.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. There is an example of a non-nilpotent group with the normalizer condition, i.e., $H<N_G(H)$ for all proper subgroups $H$. It was constructed by Heineken and Mohamed in 1968. The paper is

*A group with trivial centre satisfying the normalizer condition*, J. Algebra **10**, 368-376 (1968).

Edit: This group is seriously wonky. From their paper, it has:

- $Z(G)=1$.
- $G'$ is of exponent $p$ and abelian
- Every proper subgroup of $G$ is subnormal and nilpotent.